# SQL query to get field value distribution dynamically

Tags: sql

Is there a way to get the value distribution for a field in SQL dynamically?

I have a table with 250 fields. I would like to get the value distribution for each of these fields:

```
field0

value0: 10
value1: 100
value2: 30
...
valueN: X

field1

value0: 2
value1: 124
value2: 8
...
valueN: Y


....
```

I know that with case + sum it is possible to generate this but then the possible values have to be put in the query in advance:

```
SELECT 
    , Sum( Case When field0 = value0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As [0]
    , Sum( Case When field0 = value1 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As [1]
    , Sum( Case When field0 = value2 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As [2]
    , Sum( Case When field0 = value3 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As [3]
    , Sum( Case When field0 = valueN Then 1 Else 0 End ) As [4]
FROM table
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Wait a minute. 250 Columns...!? Fire the architect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an a way  for rows  result  (not columns result ) using aggregation function eg: count

```
SELECT field0, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY field0
```

if you want a columns result as in your code  . for some DB brand there are PIVOT functionatlities .

Answer (score 1):

With [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) you could do something like this:

```
select t.name as column_name, 
       sum(val::int) as sum
from data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d) - 'id') as t(name, val)
group by t.name;
```

The `- 'id'` removes the `id` attribute from the generated JSON. Another option to only include certain columns in the aggregation is to add a `where` condition:

```
select column_name,
       sum(val::int) as sum
from (       
  select t.name as column_name, 
         t.val
  from data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d)) as t(name, val)
) t
where column_name like 'col%'
group by column_name;
```

With the following sample table:

```
create table data 
(
  id serial primary key,
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int,
  col4 int,
  col5 int
);

insert into data (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
values 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
(11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
```

The query would return:

```
column_name | sum
------------+----
col1        |  18
col2        |  21
col5        |  30
col4        |  27
col3        |  24
```